# CSS Overflow used jQuery drop down menu. Not working in Chrome. Menu Disappears.

Tags: jquery, css

I've been trying to add a auto-suggest drop down menu using jQuery. Everything is working fine. I tried to add a scroll bar using CSS (overflow) the scroll bar shows up but when I try to scroll down the options, the drop down list disappear as I click on the scroll. Also, the scroll doesn't move the screen when I try to move it using the arrow keys. Everything works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. Any suggestion?

http://www.bylc.org/apply-bblt "Current / Last Attended Institution:" Part!

Answer (score 1):

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'autocompleteArray'` prevents running the script.

Comment: I have fixed this jQuery problem. It happened because jQuery was loaded several times. Can you plz check the drop down menu now? When I try to scroll it, why does the menu disappear in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

In the form_manager.js file try to place the jQuery.fn.autocomplete and jQuery.fn.autocompleteArray and jQuery.fn.indexOf functions inside a

```
(function($){
    <your functions>
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The drop down menu is working but the scroll bar disappears when I try to scroll through the list in Chrome. :S

Comment: I am also facing the same issue for chrome, when I am trying to click on dropdown scroll, it get disappears.